# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 [Spark / Java /UPSERT]

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm trying to update values using JDBC on spark and I continue to get the same error .

I used the following query

```
 statement.addBatch(("INSERT INTO gasoil_summeries " + "VALUES ("
                        + "'" + row.getAs("id_vehicule2")+"'"
                         + "'" + row.getInt(0)+"'"
                        +"'" + row.getAs("litre2")+"'"
                        +"'" +row.getDouble(1)+"'"
                        + "'"+row.getAs("count2")+"'"
                        +"'" + row.getInt(2)+"'"
                        +"'" + row.getAs("is_sup2")+"'"
                        +"'"+row.getInt(3)+"'"
                        +"'" +row.getAs("last_upd2")+"'"
                        +"'"+row.getTimestamp(4)+"'"
                        +")  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE _id_vehicule='" + row.getAs("id_vehicule2") + "';"));
```

the number of columns is the same,  but I continue to get the error "java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Thnak you.

Comment: It seems that you need to join this dataframes. Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , maybe that can help someone .

```
 statement.addBatch(("INSERT INTO gasoil_summeries " + "VALUES ("
                        +"'" + row.getAs("id_vehicule2") + "'"+ ","
                         //"'" + row.getInt(0)+"'"+
                        +"'" + row.getAs("litre2")+ "'"+ ","
                       // +"'" +row.getDouble(1)+"'"+
                       + "'"+row.getAs("count2")+ "'"+ ","
                      //  "'" + row.getInt(2)+"'"+
                       +"'" + row.getAs("is_sup2")+ "'"+ ","
                     //   "'"+row.getInt(3)+"'"+
                       + "'" +row.getAs("last_upd2")+ "'"+
                      //  "'"+row.getTimestamp(4)+
                ")  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_vehicule = '"+ row.getInt(0)+"',d_littre= '"+row.getDouble(1)+"',counter = '"+row.getInt(2)+"',is_suspect ='"+row.getInt(3)+"',last_update='"+row.getTimestamp(4)+ "' ; "));
```